# Solve complex equation $\cos z = j\pi$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do you solve

$$\cos z = j\pi$$

I am not sure what to do with the right side. Can someone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Is $j$ intended to be an integer?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Engineers often use it to mean $i$.

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$\cos z=\sin(2n\pi+\frac\pi2 -z)=-i \sinh(i2n\pi+i  \frac\pi2-iz)=i \pi$$

Then,

$$i2n\pi+i  \frac\pi2-iz=-\sinh^{-1}\pi$$

which yields the solutions

$$z=2n\pi+ \frac\pi2-i \sinh^{-1}\pi$$

Comment: I guess you got there first, so I have upvoted yours!

Comment: @almagest - appreciate the kindness